c# Selenium script to alter xhr requests doesn't always work
so I try to write a console app in c# that uses selenium on a website, the website on load sends a few xhr requests and I try to intercept one of them by it's name to log some data to the local storage to read it later on,
My problem is sometimes it works and sometimes not so I need either to fix that
Or on the other hand one other way I thought about it that didn't work for some reason for me is to wait for the page to fully load and then to read the file and get it's response, but I can't seem to find how to find the file using code
I've added the code I used bellow, I tried putting it before the navigation to the page, didn't work 100%
Thanks
const originalXhrOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
const originalXhrSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function (method, url) {
    this._url = url; // Store the URL for later use
    return originalXhrOpen.apply(this, arguments);
};

XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function () {
    const xhr = this;
    this.addEventListener("load", function () {
        if (xhr._url && xhr._url.includes("group")) {
            try {
                localStorage.setItem("CarsData", xhr.responseText);
                console.log("Saved!");
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("Error saving to localStorage:", error);
            }
        }
    });
    return originalXhrSend.apply(this, arguments);
};

Trying to override how xhr works, it doesn't apply to all of the requests

This is JavaScript code. Can you [edit] your question to include the C# code too?
